# Texture mapping landscape

Tags: uv

I have a landscape, with roads, hills, mountains, rivers and lots of little details, everything is modelled by hand.

Is there an easy way to produce UV maps for such landscape? I've tried different kinds of unwrapping, but all of them produce severely skewed UVs.

The easiest way I found is to use *Project from View*, but I have to manually scale and adjust texture maps, which is very tedious.

Here is an example: I have to manually move vertex UVs to make them line up with the road texture.

[image: Example]

Comment: Do you need to UV map? One option would be to use a Texture Paint and then you can manually apply the textures and use blending techniques inside blender in a 3d view. If you DO need to use a UV map, I would separate the different objects (E.G. the roads) by marking seams along the length of the road and unwrapping that way so that the different landmarks are separated

Comment: I do need the UV map, because I am exporting the model. Separating parts of the world might help, but I still don't know how to make texture "follow" curved secions of the road, except for doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 3d View combined with the already unwrapped UV to paint the [texture](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Textures/Paintinghttps://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Textures/Painting). The relevant part is:

> Paint the mesh in the 3D View, and let Blender use the currently selected UV map to update the UV Texture ("Projection Painting")

To do that, you first need to unwrap your object which you have done. Nice!
[image: UV Unwrap]
Second, you need to switch into texture paint mode
[image: TexturePaint]

You will see on the right panel a message that says "Missing Data" You don't have anything to paint on yet! Select "Add Paint Slot" and choose *Diffuse Color*
[image: Diffuse Color]

From here you will be prompted to choose a size of the canvas, and to name it. I suggest you start with 2048 as it is easier to scale down than scale up. If you need to get up close and personal with your road, use a higher resolution.

[image: Create canvas]

We're almost at the fun part!
[image]
if you go to your properties window, you can see that a new material has been added to your object. Great! But, its all black. Not so great. To fix that we need to navigate one more tab to the right and see the Textures Tab.
[image]

Cool! I have renamed this base texture (the Canvas) as DiffuseRoad because we are building a road. However, we need another texture to paint ON to our canvas. To do this, select the texture box below and choose "New Texture". Open your road texture image in this texture and name it something useful: In my case, I only have assets of wood so I chose my wood texture and named it "PaintTexture" because thats what we will be doing with it!

[image]
[image]

From here, return to your side bar and select the "texture" red/white checker icon. Choose your texture, in my case "PaintTexture"
[image]

Now paint directly onto your 3d model! You should probably adjust the strength to 1 instead of .5, unless you do plan on mixing with a few textures. If you do need more textures, just go back to your Textures tab and add some more the same way as previously and select them.
[image]
Now select the DiffuseRoad texture that was created for us and choose it to be our UV Background, that way as you paint your model you can see in real time how your UV will look.

[image]
[image]

Once you are happy with how you have painted your model, be sure to save the UV as a separate image so you don`t lose it!

[image]