# Can I "Paint" on my Objects?

Tags: texture-painting

I hate to compare programs, but I am looking for a specific feature in Blender that is used in Maya. When in Maya, you can go to the render menu and use the "3D paint tool" to give color and texture to your objects. You can view those in real time, while editing, without having to render every single time that you move your object. Is there anything like this in Blender? Thank you in advance!!

Ethan

Comment: Maybe related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15301/cant-paint-texture

Comment: See my comment on a different thread here: Step by step how to unwrap and get into a texture paint mode, and then how to add canvas and finally how to paint your texture on. http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/65868/30030

Answer (score 4):

1: Select cube in edit mode with <kbd>A</kbd> and press *Smart UV Project* (Cycles blender mode).

[image]

2: In *UV Image Editor* press *New Image* and create your texture (P.S. don't forget save your texture with <kbd>F3</kbd> save as a image).

[image]

3: In *Node Editor* press check box for use nodes (red box) and with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> from texture menu select: *Image Texture* and your image.

[image]

4: Select *Texture Paint* and start painting.

[image]

Comment: I think it would help if you said *how* to do those steps, otherwise I don't think a beginner in blender would be able to follow those steps.

Comment: I don't know what a lot of that means...I think I found UV UN-wrap...I press U in edit mode and then clicked Unwrap....but when I went into texture paint, it made everything purple...and after messing around, I accidentally got it to work (I still don't know how) and then whenever I went back to object mode, the textures didn't appear, so I couldn't fly around the image (which I need to be able to do in order to present it...)

Comment: I update my answer to be more clearer